# __nat class in clang standard libary

Tags: c++, clang, std, shared-ptr

I was looking through clang's C++ standard library, and found this class in the `shared_ptr` class.

```cpp
class shared_ptr
// ...
private:
    struct __nat {int __for_bool_;};
// ...
};
```

I understand that this class is used to detect whether type conversion is possible at compile time, but its member `__for_bool_` is never used anywhere in the class or the `weak_ptr` counterpart. So, my question is, what is the point of `__for_bool_`? Why not simply use an empty class for the same purpose?

I'm sure the standard library authors definitely know better than me.

Comment: Can you link the file and indicate the lines of code where the struct is declared? It would help to understand better the context where it is used.